# How to approach fee clawback?

Tags: communication, new-job, transition

My new employer has agreed to pay for my fees (tuitions only) owing to the old company once I end my contract with them for a maximum amount of 10k, but it turns out I only owe 2k. However I also have 8k of maternity top up fees owing to the old company that I haven’t discussed with the new employer. Is it okay to ask to see if my new employer can cover my maternity leave top up by the remaining 8k? Or does it look bad?

Comment: So, your new employer is willing to pay your current employer so you can join your new company sooner?

Comment: Yes. Would you recommend me ask that question?

Comment: because I thought my tuition fee is already too high so I originally plan to pay for mat leave top up myself. That is why I didn’t discuss this with the new employer.

Comment: I kinda worry that as you didn't mention the maternity before, but only do now when there is suddenly this "agreed" 8k it will look like taking a punt, rather than legitimate money you are owed. And sometimes how something looks is more important than truth.

Comment: That’s true. Thanks for your comment. I should have brought it out to my new employer at the first place

Comment: @user122112 actually the best way was to keep better track of the loan if I may go on that little tangent, that's the key lesson for the future. Though I am also blanking on how to make this look less like a punt, so can't put an answer together, at least better than the one Cygnus gave.

Comment: Where can I find a company that will loan me 10K on top of paying me?

Comment: @Kilisi not sure what field OP is in, but I remember from software dev that when python was starting to be "the big thing" quite a few companies often offered 10k GBP sign on bonuses for senior developers in the UK, on top of covering relocation fees (i know this as I received offers in writing like that). Right skills at the right time I guess.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul the joys of living in Europe I guess, never been there, always wanted to

Comment: @Kilisi I was going to respond with "you know, borders are open" but that's not exactly true nowadays hah.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul Wif and 5 kids I can barely afford to go out the front door never mind halfway around the World ;)

Answer (score 4):

It's best if you are crystal clear with your soon-to-be employer, so I suggest you do tell them about *all* details and things that sum up to what you owe to your current company.

Fortunately, seems that 2k + 8k = 10k so it's not like you would be asking for more than your future employer is willing to pay. However, it's best to tell them so there are no surprises.

Comment: Thanks. I didn’t mention the maternity top up owing to my new employer cause I thought they would not pay for it, so I originally plan to pay for it myself. My tuition fee turns out to be lower than what I have told to my new employer, so I think perhaps I can ask them to pay for my mat leave top up since tuition fee they agreed to pay for me is way lower than what they expected. But I’m not sure if this is good to ask or not.